# should i use subquery for many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, many-to-many

I have one table for many to many relationships but didn't have constraint index for this case, let said that i have table like this 
people, clones, types,

clones trigger to people, and types trigger to clones and clones trigger to types,
clones have many types, and types have many clones

when I query like this

```
select * from clones m
join people p on p.id = m.person_id
join "CloneHasType" c on c.clone_id = m.id
join clone_types t on t.id = c.clone_type_id
```

CloneHasType is the table the many to many

the result shows all data of that clones with the types
but when in the end of that query i add `where t.type_name = "nameType"`
it was returned to that query ( or nothing )

what am i missing for this query ?

Comment: it was no problem, the query i said above with `where` not working, it shows that query on Dbeaver, not a table empty @ravioli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:  `UPPER(t.type_name) = 'NAMETYPE'`

A couple notes:

1. Postgres is case-sensitive with strings.
2. When you check for string literals, it should be done with a single quote (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`)

Comment: you are correct, but anyway, when i query different types on many to many table and result have same clones because that clones included that types, but i want result just one clone, no duplicate, how do to that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
where t.type_name = "nameType"
```

as you used double quote so engine will find column name of `nameType` but you want to compare string so you have to use single quote

```
 where t.type_name = 'nameType'
```